# Java client fails to connect to Zookeeper and HBase

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I wrote a simple HBase client program to perform CRUD operations in my HBase cluster (1 Master and 3 Region Server). The Zookeeper instance is only running in the master server and the quorum includes all the 4 servers. The cluster is running fine and can perform read/write using YCSB client (means there are nothing wrong in the server/zookeeper side).

Now in the eclipse classpath I have added all the HBase libs and hbase-0.94.7.jar (which contains the hbase-default.xml file). I have also added the original hbase-site.xml file from the cluster in the project.

Initially, I ran the client code using the unmodified hbase-default.xml and what I've found that the client is trying to communicate with the localhost for zookeeper instance. And thus ignoring the hbase-site.xml.

Then I've modified the 3 parameters which holds the public IP address of the Master/Zookpeer server and tried again. This time I am getting the below error where the client is continuously trying to connect with the Zookeeper and its other quorum members.

I have all the 4 servers in the Zookeeper quorum and lets say their IP addresses are:

- W.W.W.W // HBase master and Zookeeper Server
- X.X.X.X // HBase RS and Zookeeper Quorum Member
- Y.Y.Y.Y // HBase RS and Zookeeper Quorum Member
- Z.Z.Z.Z // HBase RS and Zookeeper Quorum Member

---

```
13/06/19 13:06:23 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=W.W.W.W:2181,X.X.X.X:2181,Y.Y.Y.Y:2181,Z.Z.Z.Z:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection

13/06/19 13:06:23 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 5828@Kamal-VAIO

13/06/19 13:06:24 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server W.W.W.W:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)

13/06/19 13:06:25 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

---

```
13/06/19 13:06:25 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid

13/06/19 13:06:25 INFO util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 2000ms before retry #1...

13/06/19 13:06:25 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server X.X.X.X:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)

13/06/19 13:06:26 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

---

... and so on

Answer (score 2):

The Problem has been solved.

### Solution:

1. Right Click on the Project in Eclipse
2. Go to Properties
3. Select Java Build Path
4. Go to Libraries
5. Click Add Class Folder
6. Add a new folder named conf
7. Press all OK
8. Copy my hbase-site.xml into the conf folder
9. Also add the ip-host lists of my HBase cluster into Win 7 hosts file and save.
10. Run the hbase codes and the client can successfully connect to Zookeeper and HBase master.

NOTE: Step 10 is must, otherwise the client will get the hostnames from the Zookeeper instance and will not able to resolve them.

Many thanks everyone.

Comment: can you share the content of your `hbase-site.xml` ?

Comment: I'm having this [trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219258/connecting-to-a-remote-hbase-instance) when establishing a connection with zookeeper without any exception

Comment: What do steps 9 & 10 even mean?  I'd like to try this but I don't understand these 2 steps...

Comment: @Dee this is because when client machine asks for hbase server machine that where HMaster is running, it tells that it is running in its localhost mean on this machine. So if you continue to place the entry 127.0.0.1 then hbase returns this address and client machine start to find HMaster on its own machine which doesn't have such thing. that is why we changed the hosts to keep everything hunky-dory. HBase is totally depending in host names you have to understand this deeply to avoid connection probs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is with kafka-client. So in this case, you have to use explicitly kafka-client dependency version **1.0.2**. sometimes other kafka-client versions giving problems. In my case after setting kafka-client version & scope "provided", the error disappeared.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```